# Scala slick primary key skipped when using .transactionally

Tags: scala, slick, akka-http

I have a route with path("employee") that does simple POST and path("transaction") what it does is it tries to add data twice to the db. But i fail it by entering a column data more than 255 chars that has max length of 255 and i get the

> ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)

which is expected. But after the "transaction" post request, when i hit the "employee" post request. The data is added to the db but skipping the employeeID because previously i had hit post on "transaction".

Here is my route:-

```
path("transaction") {
      post {
        entity(as[String]) { data =>
          complete {
            controller.insertEmployeeTwice(data).map { res =>
              HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.OK, entity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/json`, compact(Extraction.decompose(res))))
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

Controller:-

```
def insertEmployeeTwice(data: String): Future[EmployeeResult] = {
    val employee = data.parseJson.convertTo[Employee]
    ImplEmployeeRepository.insertTwice(employee)
  }
```

Repo:-

```
def insertTwice(row: Employee): Future[DbEmployee] = {
    val userId = 10
    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString
    val timeStamp = Timestamp.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date()))
    val saveData1 = DbEmployee(uuid, row.firstName, row.lastName, row.address, row.phoneNumber, row.age, timeStamp, userId)
    val lengthLastName = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec"
    val saveData2 = DbEmployee(uuid, row.firstName, lengthLastName, row.address, row.phoneNumber, row.age, timeStamp, userId)
    insertTwoRows(saveData1, saveData2)
    
  }
```

Base Repo:-

```
def insertTwoRows(r1: E, r2: E): Future[E] = {
    db.run(insertTwoRowsQuery(r1, r2))
  }



def insertTwoRowsQuery(row1: E, row2:E): DBIOAction[E, NoStream, Effect.Write with Effect.Transactional] = {
    (for {
      _ <- query returning query += row1
      r <- query returning query += row2
    } yield r).transactionally
  }
```